# How to remove null DataMember properties from the response in wcf

Tags: .net, serialization

I am returning the xml output to the browser with a wcf webservice, if a property of a DataContract is null, it still comes through in the response as

```
<Id i:nil="true" />
```

Is there a way to have it not return in the response at all?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Figured it out myself, I needed to add the following atrribute to my DataMembers

```
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
```

Comment: This do not seem to work for me... anything else I should add?

Comment: Is there not a way to specify this as the default behavior? This seems like a terrible oversight on Microsoft's part. For example, annotating every property of a class library, containing more than 100+ POCOs is simply not acceptable.

Comment: @Crush: I agree.  Anybody have a global solution for this instead of by property?

Answer (score 0):

In the class in which your property is present have a constructor. In the constructor initialize it as null. If a property of a DataContract is null, then it will not appear in your xml output.
If you want it to appear it in your output when data is present in it just instantiate it again in your class where you expose the data.