# Xml Format Error

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, serialization, xml-nil

I encountered a nullable property issue in my C# webservice project.

```
public class Header
{
    [DataMember]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public long SportId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public long TournamentId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string TournamentName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string TournamentShortName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public long StatusId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string StatusName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string StatusShortName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime MatchDate { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string MatchTime { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime? PeriodStartDate { get; set; }   

    [DataMember]
    public int? Quarter1HomeTeamScore { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int? Quarter1AwayTeamScore { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Quarter2HomeTeamScore { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Quarter2AwayTeamScore { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Quarter3HomeTeamScore { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Quarter3AwayTeamScore { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Quarter4HomeTeamScore { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Quarter4AwayTeamScore { get; set; }

}
```

This is the soap xml after serialization:

```
<LiveMatchList>
<Items>
    <ListMatch>
        <Header>
        <Quarter1HomeTeamScore xsi:nil="true"/>
        <Quarter1AwayTeamScore xsi:nil="true"/>
        <Quarter2HomeTeamScore xsi:nil="true"/>
        <Quarter2AwayTeamScore xsi:nil="true"/>
        <Quarter3HomeTeamScore xsi:nil="true"/>
        <Quarter3AwayTeamScore xsi:nil="true"/>
        <Quarter4HomeTeamScore xsi:nil="true"/>
        <Quarter4AwayTeamScore xsi:nil="true"/>
        <Id>138906</Id>
        <SportId>2</SportId>
        <TournamentId>8</TournamentId>
        <TournamentName> Eurocup</TournamentName>
        <TournamentShortName> AVK</TournamentShortName>
        <StatusId>12</StatusId>
        <StatusName> 1. Periyot</StatusName>
        <StatusShortName> 1.P</StatusShortName>
        <MatchDate>2013-03-20T00:00:00</MatchDate>
        <MatchTime> 21:30</MatchTime>
        <PeriodStartDate xsi:nil="true"/>           
    </Header>
</ListMatch>
```

I tried to view the xml in http://www.xmlgrid.net/ but could not view it because of `xsi:nil = "true"` nodes. And in another project, which uses this webservice, I have wrong xml format error while deserializing to object.

How can I ignore null property? Or is there another way around this issue?

i tried :

```
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
public int? Quarter1HomeTeamScore { get; set; }
```

and

```
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
public int Quarter1HomeTeamScore = 0
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Representing Null values differently when serializing objects to XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362313/representing-null-values-differently-when-serializing-objects-to-xml)

Answer (score 1):

Add [EmitDefaultValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.emitdefaultvalue.aspx) attribute like this:

```
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
```

**UPDATE**

Try **IsRequired** attribute like

```
 [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
```

And as you commented it is not working for you, check this out

[How to remove null DataMember properties from the response in wcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118690/how-to-remove-null-datamember-properties-from-the-response-in-wcf)