# How to use overloading Constructor properly on c# wcf

Tags: c#, wcf

I am following a tutorial and trying to pass some data in json format.
I have tried to overload the constructor thinking it will display different data but this is not the case.

On both cases i get the same output.

this is my interface:

```
namespace JsonWcfService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IGetJson
    {

        // display user`s department
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "json/userDepartment/{name}")]
        List<Departments> userDepartments(string name);


        // display user`s app
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "json/userApp/{name}")]
        List<Departments> userApp(string name);       

    }
}
```

this is my class:

```
namespace JsonWcfService
{
    public class GetJson : IGetJson
    {

        //display user`s departments
        public List<Departments> userDepartments(string name)
        {
            List<Departments> listUserDepartments = new List<Departments>();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["tabletConnection"].ToString()))
            {
                conn.Open();

                string cmdStr = String.Format("SELECT users.userName, users.departmentID, department.departmentName, users.isActive FROM users,department "
                    + "WHERE users.departmentID = department.departmentID "
                    + "AND userName = '" + name +"'");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn);
                SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (rd.HasRows)
                {
                    while (rd.Read())
                        listUserDepartments.Add(new Departments(rd.GetString(0), rd.GetInt32(1), rd.GetString(2), rd.GetString(3)));
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
            return listUserDepartments;
        }


        //display user`s app
        public List<Departments> userApp(string name)
        {
            List<Departments> listUserApp = new List<Departments>();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["tabletConnection"].ToString()))
            {
                conn.Open();

                string cmdStr = String.Format("SELECT * FROM application");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn);
                SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (rd.HasRows)
                {
                    while (rd.Read())
                        listUserApp.Add(new Departments(rd.GetInt32(0), rd.GetString(1)));
                }
                conn.Close();
            }

            return listUserApp;
        }

    }


    [DataContract]
    public class Departments
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int departmentId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string departmentName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string userName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string isActive { get; set; }

        public Departments(int temp_departmentId, string temp_departmentName)
        {
            departmentId = temp_departmentId;
            departmentName = temp_departmentName;
        }

        public Departments(string temp_userName, int temp_departmentId, string temp_departmentName, string temp_isActive)
        {
            userName = temp_userName;
            departmentId = temp_departmentId;
            departmentName = temp_departmentName;
            isActive = temp_isActive;
        }
    }
}
```

output for constructor 1:

{"userAppResult":[{"departmentId":1,"departmentName":"A","isActive":null,"userName":null},{"departmentId":2,"departmentName":"A","isActive":null,"userName":null},{"departmentId":3,"departmentName":"A","isActive":null,"userName":null},{"departmentId":4,"departmentName":"A","isActive":null,"userName":null},{"departmentId":5,"departmentName":"A","isActive":null,"userName":null}]}

output for constructor 2:

{"userDepartmentsResult":[{"departmentId":1,"departmentName":"A","isActive":"Y","userName":"b"},{"departmentId":2,"departmentName":"A","isActive":"Y","userName":"b"},{"departmentId":3,"departmentName":"A","isActive":"Y","userName":"b"}]}

Comment: What output are you looking to have?

Comment: Ditch this tutorial. [WCF REST services are old and no longer maintained](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj823172%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If you want to build a REST service, use ASP.NET WebAPI. Your use of inline SQL also makes your service susceptible to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I have updated the question, added the output i get

Comment: Well, what do the selects return when you execute them?

Comment: Shouldn`t constructor 1 (userAppResult) return only  departmentId and departmentName? That is what i am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with overloading. You're trying to let WCF not serialize properties that don't have a value set. The serializer doesn't know which constructor you called, so it's just going to serialize the entire object, including all properties marked as `DataMember`.

There are a couple ways to do so. You can set the `EmitDefaultValue` of the `DataMember` attribute to `false` to ignore properties that have a default value, as explained in [how to not return null when a Data member field is not set in the data contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685045/how-to-not-return-null-when-a-data-member-field-is-not-set-in-the-data-contract) and [How to remove null DataMember properties from the response in wcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118690/how-to-remove-null-datamember-properties-from-the-response-in-wcf).

You could also use the [`ShouldSerialize` convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394587/shouldserialize-pattern-and-datacontractserializer).

Also note [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050198/how-to-use-overloading-constructor-properly-on-c-sharp-wcf/30051174#comment48215963_30050198), when this is for learning purposes I'd suggest looking into ASP.NET WebAPI as opposed to WCF REST. You also should use [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174792/does-using-parameterized-sqlcommand-make-my-program-immune-to-sql-injection) instead of manually crafting SQL by string concatenation with user-provided variables.